# Odds of winning plus odds of losing do not equal 100% ???

Tags: probability

If i have four dice i calculate the chances of getting at least one 2 as 864 ÷1296 = 66,66% since if on one dice a 2 comes up then it does not matter what comes up on the other 3 dice (1×6×6×6 possible outcomes × 4 times = 864), i still have thrown a two.

If i now work out the chances of not throwing at least one two, it 5×5×5×5 ÷ 1296 = 48,23%.

when i add these two together i get way over 100 %. What am i doing here wrong ??????

Comment: Your first calculation is incorrect, as you count the instances in which you get more than one $2$ multiple times.  In fact, I'd say it's best to do the first part by doing the second part (which you did correctly) and subtracting from $1$.

Comment: Look up the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 1):

The probability of no dice showing a two is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4\approx 48.22\%$. The probability of at least one dice showing a two consequently is $1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4\approx 51.77\%$. You can also obtain this number combinatorially. Start with one dice. The probability of getting at lest one two is $\frac{1}{6}$. If you have two dice, you have the cases 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 1-2, 3-2, 4-2, 5-2, 6-2, which are eleven out of the thirty-six possible cases. Note that you get $\frac{6}{36}+\frac{5}{36}$ since you can't count the case 2-2 twice. This is basically the error you did in your calculations. Working things out properly, you obtain only $671$ cases with at least one two.

Comment: Brilliant answers. Thank you all for the explanations,I get it now (after 10 mins with pen and paper, lol) Another heurism that i will have to look out for.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with one of the answers, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The only flaw in your calculation is where you calculate the number of ways of getting at least one 2. As lulu pointed out, you can easily calculate it by computing the second part. I shall simply demonstrate how to determine the first explicitly (directly) :

Number of ways of getting at least one head = Number of ways of getting exactly $1$ head + Number of ways of getting exactly 2 heads + Number of ways of getting exactly 3 heads + Number of ways of getting exactly 4 heads

$= {4\choose 1} \cdot (1.5.5.5) + {4 \choose 2}\cdot (1.1.5.5) +{4\choose 3} \cdot (1.1.1.5)+{4\choose 4}\cdot (1.1.1.1)$

$= 4.125+6.25+4.5+1$

$= 500+150+20+1$

$=671$

$=1296-625$

= Total number of possibilities - Number of ways of getting no 2 (as required)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake with the first part of your calculation. When you fix 2 on one die and considering all possibilities for other dies you are including possibilities of getting 2 on other dies also. Example if you get 2 on first die and 3 2 4 on other dies then getting 2 3 2 4 on respective dies is counting twice when you fix 2 on first die and when you fix 2 on third die. So to avoid this mistake it is always better to calculate answer for second part first and subtracting that answer from 1 to obtain required answer.